# Django is checking my ListView again when I am leaving it

Tags: python, django

I got two views, when I go to the url(view1) the view1's Template works perfectly, but, in that template I have a link that send me to the url(view2) and when I click it, the browser show me an error that belongs to the view1. Even if I manually type the second url, it shows me the error from the view1.

**Browser Url**

> activation/?tpr=2104813&idpr=50

**View1**

```
class Activation_vw(ListView):
    queryset = STATE.objects.order_by('name')
    context_object_name = 'states_list'
    template_name = 'activation.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
        tokenProspect_v = request.GET.get('tpr')
        idProspect_v = request.GET.get('idpr')

        preRegist_qr = PRE_REGIST_USER.objects.filter(
            id=idProspect_v).values('id', 'email', 'token')

        if int(tokenProspect_v) != int(preRegist_qr[0]['token']):
            msg_v = (
                "Wrong URL")
            error_v = True
        else:
            request.session['idProspecto'] = idProspecto_v
            msg_v = ""
            error_v = False

        context = self.get_context_data(msg=msg_v, error=error_v)
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

**Template1**

```
{% if error %}
    {{ msg | safe }}
{% else %}
    {% for state in states_list %}
            <a href="activation-2?idState={{ state.id }}"> 
                <div>{{ state.name }} </div>
            </a>
    {% empty %}
        <p>Empty list.</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

**Error**

> TypeError at /activation-2 int() argument must be a string or a
>   number, not 'NoneType'

**Error Traceback**

```
257. if int(tokenProspect_v) != int(preRegist_qr[0]['token']):
```

The line 257 belongs to the view1

**Edited:**
I forgot to say:
If I manually add the parameters for the view1, it works like if django is still loading the view1

> activation-2?idState=5&tpr=2104813&idpr=50

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure how you generating your token with every user,

in this case your token is None, and you are trying to cast to int

this may be the problem

Comment: One token is already in the DB, and the otherone is in the url as a variable, when I load the url for the view1, everything works perfectly. But when I try to load the view2 changing the url at the browser, is like the browser keeps loading the view1 instead.

Comment: I don't know what happens, but I changed the names at the urlpatterns and it works now.
It was like:
`urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^activation', Activation_vw.as_view(), name='activation'),
    url(r'^activation-2/$', Activation2_vw.as_view(), name='activation-2')]`
And I changed their names to 'chooseState' and 'chooseCity' and it works

Comment: You didn't terminate the first expression, "activation", so it was also matching "activation-2". Make sure you always use a $ at the end of the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

As @Daniel Roseman said, the problem was in the end of the url pattern, I didn't terminate the first expression with the $, so it must be like this:

```
urlpatterns = [ 
url(r'^activation$', Activation_vw.as_view(), name='activation'),
url(r'^activation-2/$', Activation2_vw.as_view(), name='activation-2')
]
```